# Why does Phpmyadmin bookmark Textfield not appear?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I use Phpmyadmin version 5.1.1 and Mysql on docker but when I open a table and execute query
`Textfield bookmark this SQL query` not found.
as appear in this image.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I executed this SQL script in PHPMyAdmin manually

```
https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/blob/master/sql/create_tables.sql
```

and bookmarks and other features are worked automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have configured the [**phpMyAdmin configuration storage**](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#phpmyadmin-configuration-storage) for using bookmarks feature. Once you have done that, you can use bookmarks in the SQL tab.

Comment: Thanx Mr. Rob Moll
But I can't understand the way in the PHPMyAdmin document.
Can you give me another clear way?